# compare grouped slopes (change over time)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, lm

I have a set of measurements over time at specific locations with treatments applied to different locations. I'm interesting in testing whether locations have different responses to the treatments overall. Each location may have different 'starting points' so I care about slopes of a linear model, not intercepts or means.

I have figured out how to estimate a linear model for each location individually and then use a t-test on slopes (for two treatments), but I expect that's not fully legit and am stuck trying to specify an appropriate mixed model.

Here's a reprex

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2) #just to show what I'm looking for

#Set up dummy data
dat <- data.frame(samples = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3), rep(5,3),rep(6,3)),
           value = c(1,3,7, 2,4.5,4.2, 7,7.2,10, 5,2,2, 9,9,2, 2,1,0.5),
           time = rep(c(1,2,3),6),
           tmt = c(rep(1,9), rep(2,9)))
dat$samples <- as.factor(dat$samples)
dat$tmt <- as.factor(dat$tmt)

# plot it to visualize what I'm looking for
# do the slopes of the two tmt groups differ?
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=value, group=samples)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=tmt))+
  geom_point()

# I assume this isn't really a legitimate way to test the groups of slopes!
tmt1_estimates <- lmList(value ~ time | samples, data=dat, subset = dat$tmt == 1)
summary(tmt1_estimates)

tmt2_estimates <- lmList(value ~ time | samples, data=dat, subset = dat$tmt == 2)
summary(tmt2_estimates)

tmt1_slopes <- summary(tmt1_estimates)$coefficients[,,"time"][,"Estimate"]
tmt2_slopes <- summary(tmt2_estimates)$coefficients[,,"time"][,"Estimate"]
# the test
t.test(tmt1_slopes, tmt2_slopes)

# my attempt at specifying in lmer. I feel like I'm missing the comparison of 
# slopes by tmt group
m1 <- lmer(value ~ tmt + (time|samples), data=dat)
summary(m1)
```

Any advice for a more appropriate test would be greatly appreciated. In reality, my samples are unbalanced (different sized groups) and vary in when sampled.

Comment: Duncan, C., Jones, K., & Moon, G. (1998). [Context, composition and heterogeneity: Using multilevel models in health research](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kelvyn-Jones/publication/13765545_Context_Composition_and_Heterogeneity_Using_Multilevel_Models_in_Health_Research/links/5a008a134585159634bad3d8/Context-Composition-and-Heterogeneity-Using-Multilevel-Models-in-Health-Research.pdf). *Social Science & Medicine*, 46(1), 97–117.

Comment: @Alexis thank you, interesting paper but not sure it helps me specify the model correctly, even as a multi-level model.   ?

Comment: It should help orient you towards understanding inference about **distributions of multiple slopes**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this model:

```
library(lmerTest)
fit1 <- lmer(value ~ time * tmt + (time|samples), data=dat)
#boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
summary(fit1)
```

However, with your example data, it fits perfect (negative) correlation between random intercept and random slope. You could try providing better starting values to the solver but looking at the plot it seems justified to remove the random slope:

```
fit2 <- lmer(value ~ time * tmt + (1|samples), data=dat)
plot(fit2)
#no obvious issues, maybe some heteroskedasticity, but not enough data to assess that further 
summary(fit2)
anova(fit2)
#Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
#         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
#time      0.008   0.008     1 10.0000  0.0030 0.957318   
#tmt      11.307  11.307     1  9.5941  4.5403 0.060083 . 
#time:tmt 42.941  42.941     1 10.0000 17.2419 0.001973 **
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The interaction term `time:tmt` represents the difference between the slopes of the two treatments. In the example it is significant.

The perfect correlation between random slope and random intercept in `fit1` indicates that any sample-effect on slope seems to be due to the different starting points (at time 0). If you try a model without correlation, i.e., `value ~ time * tmt + (time||samples)`, the fit is still singular and the random slope is estimated to be zero. Thus, I would conclude that there is no evidence of the location having a strong effect on the slopes.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I appreciate your discussion about adding/removing the different random effects.